# How to get value from data attribute in react hook form

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

I have `select` tag with `options` as follows:

```
<select className="form-control" placeholder="Category name" name='categoryName'
        {...register('categoryName')} defaultValue={formData.categoryName} onChange={(e) => selectedIdOnChange(e, 'data-id')}>
        {categories.map((item) => <option key={item._id} data-id={item._id}>{item.categoryName}</option>)}
</select>
```

How do I get value from data attribute `data-id` on submit?